# bash cript: ssh create file; sleep 3m; rm file;

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsync

Trying to create a script that will `ssh` into server, backup some files, sleep for 3 minutes, then remove the files.

While it's sleeping the same script is back to local and `rsync` the file. Then when the 3 minutes are up... file is removed.

Just trying this so as to not connect twice with ssh.

```
ssh $site "
tar -zcf $domain-$date.tar.gz $path;
{ sleep 3m && rm -f $domain-$date.tar.gz };
"

rsync -az $site:$domain-$date.tar.gz ~/WebSites/$domain/BackUp/$date;
```

I tried with command grouping with (), to create a sub command, but I think the variable would not be read. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ssh command will sleep for 3 minutes and remove the files, then your script proceeds to try to rsync the files that got removed. There is no easy workaround for having your first ssh command sleep while your own script proceeds to run rsync.

Do either:

1. ssh into the server twice. After rsync completes, ssh into the server again and remove the files.
2. Tell rsync to remove the files after it's synced them. Add the `--remove-source-files` to rsync.

Comment: Was trying to be "clever" by sleeping in the background but yeah... Option 2 did the trick. Thanks!